# Resizing an image with percentage attribute

Tags: css, image, resize

I am having a problem resizing an image with the percentage attribute. I am trying to resize the image so that it is a percentage of its container. This works fine in a Chrome, but in internet explorer and firefox, it resizes it as a percentage of the original image, and not to fit its container. Are there any work arounds to get it to do what I want in explorer and firefox?

Comment: Can you please provide example code, preferably in a JSFiddle?

Comment: I've never heard about that (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-width)

Comment: <img src = "source" height = "77%">  It works if I replace height with width, but that doesn't really suit this particular application.

Comment: @user981053 can you give a http://jsfiddle.net example of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this test:

- `<div>` container set at `800px`
- and a child `<img>` within at 1000x1000 image `width:50%`

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/QdmuD/

All browsers showed the image at 400x400 (*50% of the container*)

Tested in Chrome (dev build), FF 8, IE 9 (and 7,8 compat modes)

Comment: For some reason width works, but I actually need to scale using the height attribute. Sizing with width works in all browsers, but height only works in chrome.

Comment: is your container set to a specific height?

Comment: Yes, the height of the container is set.

Comment: Is your image a direct child of the container?

Comment: I finally figured it out, and the problems was that I had a div inside of a div, in which the child div there was no height specified. Thank you for the continued help.